# Best way to upgrade Time Machine volume to APFS and preserve backups?

Tags: backup, time-machine, catalina, apfs

Currently my TM backups are on an HFS volume. I would like to switch to APFS (for snapshots etc.)

I assume I have to erase the drive and re-format it as APFS.

What's the 'correct' way to save my current backup history? Can I just copy `Backups.backupdb` to another HFS drive, then copy it back to the new APFS drive, via Finder? (With TM turned off of course.)

Also, my current `Backups.backupdb` contains backups from 2 machines. I only need to preserve the backups for 1 of them. Can I copy just that subfolder?

(macOS Catalina)

Comment: Catalina can't use APFS for Time Machine, only HFS+. Big Sur uses APFS. See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15139/10.15/mac/10.15 [& change the OS in the top menu to see both 10.15 & 11]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot preserve the backups while upgrading the disk to APFS. The structure of the backups are fundamentally different and incompatible.

Comment: I see. Can I at least somehow copy to the 2nd drive for archive purposes?

Comment: @Dan Better to use the 2nd drive for new APFS backup and keep the old drive untouched until you are ready to erase the old backups.

Comment: @Gilby, yes that makes sense, but I have to use the old drive because it's a firm-issued 'padlock' secure drive.

Comment: You could but it would take a very long time to copy. If you want to ensure you don't go without a backup, complete a backup to your second drive and then reset the first drive and complete all future backups to that one.

Comment: @Ezekiel If you could cite a source for your information, it would help others confirm whether it's fact or rumor, and within what contexts it applies. For example, here is information to the contrary, so it's hard to know who to believe: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/450554/90402

Comment: My primary source is that Apple provides no indication that should work, and the man pages for associatedisk make no mention of transforming from HFS+ to APFS. Instead, they say it should be used to re-link a source computer to an existing backup history (such as after restoring a backup to a new computer, and not wanting to start anew)

That answer may very well work, but I would say it's on the other answerer to provide proof.